# Load Image Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, image-manipulation

I am trying to load data from a particular directory that contains more than 10M images are there and 10K classes but the problem is I don't have a different directory for all classes, all the images are in one directory only. I have a CSV file label that contains id and label. and I am trying to use the `VGG16` model.

```
CSV:
id,lable
abf20a,CAR
dsf8sd,BIKE
```

here abf20a is image name `"abf20a.jpg"`

so please help me here how can I load images and labels together and train the model using `VGG16`

thanks

Vishal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ImageDataGenerator's flow_from_dataframe method to load the images using a CSV file.
**Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data/img/new.csv')

# Data augmentation pipeline
train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()

# Reading files from path in data frame
train_ds = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df,directory = 'data/img/new', x_col = 'filename', y_col = 'label')
```

**The Dataframe looks like this:**

```
    filename    label
0   Capture.PNG 0
```

If you just have id in your filename. You can use pandas apply method to add jpg extension.

```
df['id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: '{}.jpg'.format(x))
```

For a complete set of data augmentation options provided by `ImageDataGenerator`, you can look at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#expandable-1).

For a complete set of options for `flow_from_dataframe`, you can look at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe).

With this, you don't have to worry about mismatching labels as this is an inbuilt TensorFlow method. Also, the files are loaded as and when necessary which avoids cluttering your main memory.

For training you can simply use:

```
model.fit(
        train_ds,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_ds,
        validation_steps=800)
```

Comment: `train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df,directory = 'data/img/new', x_col = 'filename', y_col = 'label')` if i dont pass directory and pass all the image path in x_col as a file path intead of filename like `train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df,x_col = 'filepath', y_col = 'label')` will is work?

Comment: Yes, since my `df` only contains `capture.png` and this file is located in `data/img/new` I used a directory argument. But if you have complete file paths like `data/img/new/capture.png` you can skip using the `directory` attribute. Note `x_col` and `y_col` are the column names of the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

0. get list of filenames in alphabetical order using `os.walk(directory)`
1. read the csv file and generate `labels_list` list with class labels in same order as filenames.
   use
2. use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` with parameter `label=labels_list`

This will give you a `tf.data.Dataset` that you can feed to the training function.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can iterate the csv file using the ID label to read images.
For instance:

```
import csv 

csv_path = 'your_csv_path'
images_base_path = 'your_images_path'

images=[]
labels=[] 

with open(csv_path, newline='',encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
      spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
      for row in spamreader:
          # And than you can do like this:
          # images_complete_path = images_base_path +  row[0]
          # images.append(imread(images_complete_path))
          # labels.append(row[1])
```

And than you obtain images and labels.
This is only an idea, you can implement it easily.
Hope it can be helpful.

Comment: yes this will work but for a large dataset it needs more computation power

Comment: I think that the problem can be more related to memory error rather than computational power, so in this case you can try to use the same procedure for batches of images creating more than one dataset. If you're using google colab you shouldn't have computation problems.

Comment: I am using Kaggle's notebook if I run for a loop it's tacking too much time to run on whole data. because I run per 10k data it was tacking nearly 7min.

Comment: I think that is normal that such a large dataset require too much time. Another solution can be the following:
If the dataset that you're using is a known dataset, maybe you can find an online version already labeled (an h5py dataset).

Comment: if data training tacking more time it's normal but data manipulation also tacking more time  that doesn't make sense